# MVC5 Use default Authorize attribute with roles using Windows Authentication and Custom UserStore

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, authorization, asp.net-identity-2

**The system**
I have and MVC5 web application using windows authentication.
There is an old database where I already have users, groups and roles.

**Aim**
Use the standard [Authorize(Roles = "myExistingRole")] without creating a custom attribute, reusing the existing roles and users in the DB.

**Current state**

- I use EF6, .net 4.5.1.
- I'm able to use the [Authorize] attribute. (OK)
- I'm able to login and User.Identity is properly populated. (OK)
- I properly extended IUser, IUserStore, IRole, IRoleStore and so on. (OK)
- I can successfully use the UserManager to get all the data I need. (OK)
- I can user the UserManager to verify if a user is in role. (OK)
- User.IsInRole("myExistingRole") return false, but should return true. (BAD)

**The problem**
The [Authorize(Roles = "myExistingRole")] never authorize me.
User.IsInRole("myExistingRole") always reply false.

**My point**
I don't know what I should do to instruct the system to use my implementation.
The only option I know I have is to create a custom attribute and register it as filter, but I'd prefer to use the standard one and maybe extend it in the future using Claims.

Can you help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also extend IUserRoleStore?

Comment: Yes Atika, also all the password and login related interfaces.

Comment: I bumped into the same issue (on asp.net core) with a hobby project of mine. Had to put in on ice do to more pressing matters but have rebooted it so will investigate the matter when i get to it if it re-occurs. Feel free to write how you solved it if you found the answer. Otherwise ill add it when ive gotten to the bottom of it. I think this could be good data to have on print..

Comment: @Baseless I went for the custom attribute option, I removed all the code and I now use the custom attribute in replacement of the default one.
I'm not happy about this solution because based on the documentation the  various stores are meant to be used exactly for this purpose.
I may try again during the next spare time.

Comment: I actually tracked down my original problem last night, tracking the issue was pretty straight forward once i understood the process. Im working with .net core but as long as its Identity 3 the process should be the same. Will write my issue, and how i solved it, below.

Comment: @Baseless Did you ever write this down? Stumbled upon the same problem.